# What would be the URL for SSO into Trailhead using org login?

Tags: single-sign-on, trailhead

I have a salesforce org with SSO set up that triggers (on our network) if you navigate to https://exampleDomain.my.salesforce.com/  (not the real custom domain). The login users use for that org is also one that they will use with trailhead.

If you go to trailhead and indicate login using salesforce you can take the URL it gives and change to the custom domain and trigger the process and end up using the SSO to directly log in to trailhead. Example URL when clicked from trailhead: 
https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DGIANTHASHCODE%253D&sdtd=1 .

The only issue I can see is that the GIANTHASHCODE is one time use.  Is there a different value we could use for that source param (which is in the startURL param)that would always just point to trailhead?

Comment: The `RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=` will be redirection from the /services/oauth2/authorize endpoint. If you knew the client_id/consumer key that Trailhead uses you could start this process yourself.